# How to do lines and write on it and change its color in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to do same thing like this picture in word:

[image]

I do not know how to change the color of the two lines from blue to black .. I do not know how to write Chapter 1 in the upper corner of the upper line ..

EDIT:

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with tab:

- Enter:

> Chapter1
>       Introduction

- Set font size of "1" as required (you may need to adjust spacing and line spacing)
- right click in first line - "paragraph.." - "tabs.." (at the bottom of the form)

  - tab stop position: enter position of right margin (16 cm by default for A4 page)
  - alignment: select "right"
  - leader: select "4 _____"
  - press set
- press tab at the beginning of the first line

[image]

Comment: It does not work for me .. please look at my edit to see

Comment: I wrote 16 cm it doesn't equal 16".